# Form in laravel giving out a strange output

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

Hey there i am very much new to laravel and am starting up with laravel 5, here i am trying to build a simple form in laravel just for some starter's but as i do i.e as i execute the page consisting my simple form in my xampp localhost(windows os) it's giving out raw html output i.e in tags, i am pretty much blank as am just a beginner to this laravel framework, please i need some help over this one pardon me if i went wrong somewere.

Here is **routes.php**

```
Route::get('form', function(){
 //render app/views/form.blade.php
 return View::make('form');
});
```

Here is **form.blade.php**

```
<!--app/views/form.blade.php-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>
   Laravel
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'form-submit')) !!}

<!-- email input -->
{{ Form::label('email','Email',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
{{ Form::email('email','hello@clivern.com',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
<!-- password inputs -->
{{ Form::label('password','Password',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
{{ Form::password('password','',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
<!-- submit buttons -->
{{ Form::submit('Save') }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
 </body>
</html>
```

*And this is the output which i get when i run it*

```
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel.dev/form-submit" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="nOdrCi1IIwBGx2ofIMfNH2xvI9xSxHGk8m8glBYf"> 
<label for="email" id="" class="">Email</label>
<input id="" class="" name="email" type="email" value="hello@clivern.com"> <label for="password" id="" class="">Password</label> 
<input name="password" type="password" value="" id="password"> 
<input type="submit" value="Save"> </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use {!! Form::**methodHere** !!} in your form facade.

Comment: sorry..but i dint get you..!

Comment: Instead of {{ Form::open() }}

Comment: use {!! Form::open() !!}

Comment: to all form facade method

Comment: {{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'form-submit')) !!}}   this what i tried but it still giving out `{
} <label for="email" id="" class="">Email</label> <input id="" class="" name="email" type="email" value="hello@clivern.com"> <label for="password" id="" class="">Password</label> <input name="password" type="password" value="" id="password"> <input type="submit" value="Save"> </form>`

Comment: single brace only {!! !!}

Comment: Got it sir thanks a ton for your help means a lot..!

Comment: i see, you only changed form::open and form::close, change also all form facade inputs. like {!! Form::text !!} {!! Form::label !!} etc..

Comment: Sir may i know why many tutorials gave {{ }} and why they dint work for me and why {!! !!} worked..?

Comment: base on my experience i dont know the exact reason, but i just notice that using {{ }} it returns data, and {!! !!} just diplays data or take the action. e.g {{ $count++ }} it increments the $count variable, but also echo'ing the $count.